# Azure Functions Python Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

```
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 242, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpExample/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
```

I get this error on Azure Functions when run online. There is a requirements.txt file which contains the pandas requirement but it still manages to not find the module name pandas. Locally the function works fine.

Comment: Could you please share some more details or screenshots of the code you import the "pandas" module and the code in "requirements.txt". And may I know the error is in local running or run on azure ?

Comment: Use module without import?

Comment: Please show more information about your questions, mainly the part you quoted.

Comment: ```import pandas as pd```
this is my import and yes the function works fine locally but this error result is outputted on the application insight logs on azure.
Reuqirements.txt :
```pandas
azure-functions
azure-functions-worker
grpcio~=1.20.1
grpcio-tools~=1.20.1
protobuf==3.6.1
six==1.11.0
# Additional packages
requests
pillow>=6.2.0```

Comment: Hi @snoogybunny, may I know how did you modify the "requirements.txt" before deploy your function from local to azure ? Modify "requirements.txt" manually or generate it automatically by command ?

Comment: i added the requirements manually but this is all pushed to azure repositories and the build and release is succeeded over there. The requirements.txt is run on build in azure and this goes through the program thorough cmdline and there is no error. Then it gets updated on azure functions but the log there returns me this error.

Comment: I'm not sure if it causes the issue, but could you please generate the "requirements.txt" automatically by the command "pip freeze > requirements.txt" on local and deploy the function to azure again. Maybe you can have a try~

Comment: Doesn't seem to work that way either

Comment: Hi @snoogybunny , as I don't know any more details of your code and environment, so I post all of my steps in the answer area for your reference. Maybe you can compare the differences between my steps and yours and find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the conversation in comments, I'm not sure what the problem is. But I post all of the steps I did just now for your reference, I follow the steps below and it didn't show the error message about import pandas.

1. I create a python function in VS Code and run the command below to install pandas in local.

```
pip install pandas
```

[image]

Then add the code "import pandas as pd" and call the pad in the main code.
[image]

2. Run the command below to generate "requirements.txt" automatically.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image]

After run this command, my "requirements.txt" show as below:

[image]

3. Crate a function app(python) on azure portal with the name of "hurypyfun" and run the command below in VS code TERMINAL to deploy the function from local to azure.

```
func azure functionapp publish hurypyfun --build remote
```

[image]

4. Wait a few minutes, after the deployment we can test it on azure portal. It shows success and it doesn't show the error message about import pandas.
   [image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~